# What can I do to stop getting Connection Pool error

Tags: c#, postgresql

I was getting quite often the following error:

Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 'The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds)'

Then I looked for possible causes and solutions in here and found out that I should be applying the `using` statement. So I reviewed all my code and did that.

However, I keep getting that error while testing a button that gets information from my database, does some calculation and writes the results in a few textboxes. It usually crashes at the fifth-ish time I click it. A piece of the code follows:

```
        private void CalcTemp(Cable cable)
        {
            string sqlString = "Server=172.19.2.40; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=password; Database=PROLIG;";
            using (NpgsqlConnection sqlCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlString))
            {
                string cmdString = @"SELECT tempamb, elevmaxonan, elevmaxonaf, elevmaxonaf2, topoil1_2, topoil1_4, especial1factor, especial1topoil,
                                especial2factor, especial2topoil, especial3factor, especial3topoil, especial4factor, especial4topoil, 
                                especial5factor, especial5topoil, especial6factor, especial6topoil FROM correntes WHERE prolig_ofs_id = @id;";
                NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", StartOF.MyOF.id);
                NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);

                //does calculation

             }
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add using to your command creation:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, sqlCon)) 
{
```

Disposing all objects which implement IDisposable is a good practice.
Since your command is not disposed of in time, your connection is not closed and returned to the pool.
It is a lot of stuff on dispose which must be executed directly (or by using).

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (State == CommandState.Disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Note: we only actually perform cleanup here if called from Dispose() (disposing=true), and not
            // if called from a finalizer (disposing=false). This is because we cannot perform any SQL
            // operations from the finalizer (connection may be in use by someone else).
            // We can implement a queue-based solution that will perform cleanup during the next possible
            // window, but this isn't trivial (should not occur in transactions because of possible exceptions,
            // etc.).
            if (_prepared == PrepareStatus.Prepared)
                _connector.ExecuteBlind("DEALLOCATE " + _planName);
        }
        Transaction = null;
        Connection = null;
        State = CommandState.Disposed;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

So you need the following code:

```
private void CalcTemp(Cable cable)
{
    string sqlString = "Server=172.19.2.40; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=password; Database=PROLIG;";
    using (NpgsqlConnection sqlCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlString))
    {
        string cmdString = @"SELECT * FROM correntes WHERE prolig_ofs_id = @id;";
        using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, sqlCon))
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", StartOF.MyOF.id);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);    
            //does calculation
        } //end using command (calls dispose on command, even if exception happens)
    } //end using connection (calls dispose on connection object, even if exception happens)
}
```

Next advice - do not use data tables in case of large amount of data. Use DataReader instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, you're saying that I have to use two `using` statements, one for the connection and one for the command? My code will lie inside those two curly brackets?

Comment: Check my updated answer, also avoid a lot of connections create/open - it can decrease performance of your app. A common pattern for such things: create a disposable object which will have a connection on it - create it once, make all calculations and dispose (with connection close when needed)